# Photo Gallery for website

Tags: photo-gallery

i want to create a photo gallery for my html website. which should contain album wise photo management. previously i was embedding picasa web album to the website. but now they have stopped support for that.  so can anybody suggest me an idea. whether i can integrate flicker or any other other photo platform which support this ?

i want the album like this. http://ahamlett.com/jQuery-Picasa-Gallery/

[image]

Comment: Picasa Web Albums Data API is still available https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol So you can use it and build your own photo library as you want

Comment: no its not working now.

Comment: I mean these requests are still work.
Requesting a list of albums
https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/{userID}
Requesting a list of photos
https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/{userID}/albumid/{albumID}

Answer (score 1):

Please try with this nanoGALLERY,

http://nanogallery.brisbois.fr/

Comment: Thank you so much prabhu.. the flickr album worked for me, u are a real life saver..